# how to use multiple columns in where clause in sql server 2005?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2005, where-clause

I want to search ID of employee by his name. so I have taken a textbox to enter his name and a search button. The ID and name of employee is stored in Employee table but the name is stored in 3 columns ie firstname, middlename and lastname.
  So my problem is how to write query for searching ID as i will have to use the above mentioned 3 columns to compare the name with the name entered in the textbox.

Please help me out with this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your current code/SQL and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: How does your table schema look like?

Comment: I will be entering fname mname and lname in one textbox ..but i am not getting how to compare it with the 3 columns in the table..like if i use query- select ID from Employee where...wat shud i write in where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
SELECT Id FROM Employee 
Where FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' '+LastName = 'Sample Name Here'
```

But you should check the space between your text entered in the textbox.

Comment: thank u..this query is working in sql..but i didnt get how to do it in code..will i have to remove the spaces between the words and store those words in 3 diff variables??

Comment: Can you post your code where your are creating your statements.